# Can't delete account from Firebase

Tags: firebase, rest, firebase-authentication

I am creating a simple app using NativeScript where administrators can add and delete users from a a Firebase database. I am being able to add the users easily, but I can't seem to figure out how to delete them. I am following the instructions found in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-delete-account

but when I submit the post request like this:

`.post(`https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:delete?key=${FIREBASE_API_KEY}`,{ "idToken": userId })` .... (the rest of the code)

I get the following error:

This is the error I am getting:

```
JS: ERROR {
JS:   "headers": {
JS:     "normalizedNames": {},
JS:     "lazyUpdate": null
JS:   },
JS:   "status": 400,
JS:   "statusText": "Bad Request",
JS:   "url": "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:delete?key=[MY_API]",
JS:   "ok": false,
JS:   "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
JS:   "message": "Http failure response for https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:delete?key=[MY_API]: 400 Bad Request",
JS:   "error": {
JS:     "error": {
JS:       "code": 400,
JS:       "message": "INVALID_ID_TOKEN",
JS:       "errors": [
JS:         {
JS:           "message": "INVALID_ID_TOKEN",
JS:           "domain": "global",
JS:           "reason": "invalid"
JS:         }
JS:       ]
JS:     }
JS:   }
JS: }
```

I have tried all sorts of things, I have checked questions here, and nothing. Another user mentioned that the user I am trying to delete needs to have signed in before I delete it, but that did not work either. If any of you has any ideas on how to proceed I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

`idToken` is not the same as the `userId`, so the first thing you need to do is "log in" (use the SDK) as the user to retrieve his token and then use that token to delete the account.

I was able to do this using the methods described in [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update. Is there a way to delete a user without doing this? I just have my app that admins log in from and I would like them to delete users from there, but this can be done the way you mentioned.